# Number of visitors to my webpage

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am trying to create a webpage using meteor which records the number of visitors to the webpage. The webpage should record and display the number of people who visited the webpage.I am just a beginner to meteor and web design ,i have no experience whatsoever in using meteor and this is my first attempt. So any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to do this by hand, or do you want to use an existing infrastructure (like google analytics)

Comment: I want to handle it by myself and not use any external application. Something like using $_SESSION in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run AWstats

> http://awstats.sourceforge.net/

and install tutorial here:

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dOF4MDn_TI0

Answer (score 0):

you can have something like this

collections\system.js

```
this.System = new Meteor.Collection('system');

Meteor.methods({
    pageViewInc: function() {
        System.update({ config: true }, { $inc: { 'stats.pageviews': 1 } });
    }
});

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    isSystemExist = System.findOne({ config: true });
    if (!isSystemExist) {
        options = {
            stats: {
                pageviews: 0
            },
            config: true
        };
        System.insert options
    }
}
```

and somewhere you can have a function use to Meteor.call 'pageViewInc'

if u use Meteor-Iron-Router

you can have call in 'after' callback

```
Meteor.call('pageViewInc');
```

you can make similar method to Posts Collection.

or there's a meteor-collection-hooks packages

it has after findOne hook  you can do it by server side.